# What is the $E$-$k$ relation of electron in valence band?

Tags: energy, electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

What is the $E$-$k$ relation of electron in valence band? $E$-$k$ relation for electron in conduction band is known but how to calculate energy of electron in valence band?